# CodeIgniter Pagination create_links() | Results not taking into account 'where' clauses

Tags: database, codeigniter, pagination

I have been working on an app in codeigniter which takes a series of optional fields and does a query on the database to return results based on the fields selected. These results are then paginated using the codeigniter pagination library.

The pagination work fine and the results are paginated, the problem is when i for instance get gender to 'male' so that only male results are returned, even though the first page works perfectly, the create_links() function renders pages for every result in the table, and when i change the page all 'where' parameters for the db->get() function are ignored. Any advice with this would be much appreciated.

Code:

Controller:

```
public function searchcharacter() {

        $data = $this->input->post();

        $gender = $data['gender'];
        $age = $data['approx_age'];
        $hairColour = $data['hair_colour'];
        $hairLength = $data['hair_length'];
        $eyeColour = $data['eye_colour'];
        $earType = $data['ear_type'];
        $weapons = $data['weapons'];

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci-animedb/site/searchcharacter';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('characters')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['num_links'] = 20;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $this->load->model('get_db');
        $results['characters'] = $this->get_db->getCharacterList($gender, $age, $hairColour, $hairLength, $eyeColour, $earType, $weapons, $config['per_page']);

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('characterlist', $results, FALSE);
        $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

Model:

```
function getCharacterList($gender, $age, $hairColour, $hairLength, $eyeColour, $earType, $weapons, $limit) {

    if ($gender != "None" && !empty($gender))
    {
      $this->db->where('gender', $gender);
    }

    if ($age != "None" && !empty($age))
    {
      $this->db->where('approx_age', $age);
    }

    if ($hairColour != "None" && !empty($hairColour))
    {
      $this->db->where('hair_colour', $hairColour);
    }

    if ($hairLength != "None" && !empty($hairLength))
    {
      $this->db->where('hair_length', $hairLength);
    }

    if ($eyeColour != "None" && !empty($eyeColour))
    {
      $this->db->where('eye_colour', $eyeColour);
    }

    if ($earType != "None" && !empty($earType))
    {
      $this->db->where('ear_type', $earType);
    }

    if ($weapons != "None" && !empty($weapons))
    {
      $this->db->where('weapons', $weapons);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('characters', $limit, $this->uri->segment(3));
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/banner1.png" alt="AnimeDB.me" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12" style="height:1px; background-color: #cccccc; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12" id="ajaxcontainer">

      <table class='table table-striped' id='resulttable' >
        <thead>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Anime</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <?php

            foreach ($characters as $row) {
              echo "<tr class='resulttr'><td><a href='" . base_url('site/character'). '/' . $row->character_id . "' ><image height=140 width=140 src='" . base_url('img/characterimage') . "/" . $row->file_path . "' /></a></td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->character_name . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->anime . "</td>";
              echo "<td class='rowid' style='display:none;'>" . $row->character_id . "</td></tr>";
            }

          ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('characters')->num_rows();
```

This is what the Pagination class uses to determine the number of links to create. You're telling it to use every row in the `characters` table.

You'll need to add your `WHERE` constraints to this query as well to get the correct number of total records.